# choose between open-source or close source

Tags: licensing, gpl-3, lgpl

if hypothetically I have developed special software, and I only want author recognition for it (leaving money aside) can i choose to distribute my creation as open source without other people usurping my work saying that they were its creators? I only want recognition as an author and be able to share it.

example: c++ was designed by Bjarne Stroustrup, but some guy wants to say that he designed c++, not Bjarne Strostrup.

Comment: Many people have written their own C++ compilers. If you write your own C++ compiler, that compiler is copyrighted to you; you wrote it. Of course, it would be untrue to say that you "designed the C++ language" as a result, but that is not a copyright or open source issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All open source licenses allow the author to maintain copyright ownership and require other users and contributors to honour and attribute that ownership.

While you can't stop anyone from copying it and saying it is theirs, by releasing your work with any open source license you get a legal standing against anyone who doesn't honour the licensing terms you use.

Comment: people can <ctrl+c & ctrl+v> my code and say it is theirs, sad :(

Comment: But only the original developer/author of that software would know each and every code written in it. And it would take months or years for a copy/paste person to understand the code base and such software's won't last longer

Comment: no need understand the code,,,, just ctrl-c and change author names in coments

Comment: @AndresCamiloSierraHormiga People can also just break a window in your house and take whatever they like. It's a dangerous world out there; that's why we have laws. :) I understand that it's more difficult to illegally usurp credit from a closed-source application, but since credit will probably be just a plain string, it's fairly easy to locate the string "Copyright Jane Doe" in a binary and replace it with "Copyright Someone Else" -- I would guess well within the threshold of achievability for a person who was sufficiently dedicated to commit such an attack against you.

Comment: open source == public domain?
¿can anyone study and change GIMP tools icons and positions and say this is from his authorship?

Comment: @AndresCamiloSierraHormiga while they can and you can't stop them initially, that will open them up to legal action. The copyright owner has the legal right to force them to remove such work, get ISP/host to remove it or block their account and sue for damages/compensation and so forth. The honest ones will honour your terms and help you make the project better, while copyright gives you the means to fight back against any dishonest ones. Just remember that there really are more good people than bad, just don't let the thought of bad things stop you.

Comment: @AndresCamiloSierraHormiga The license to copy and use GIMP source code and files does not give you the right to transfer authorship.